# White place after animation on Gingerbread

Tags: android, animation, android-2.3-gingerbread, nineoldandroids

I probably dont understant something in animation of view. The problem:
I using NineOldAndroids to animate views. Animation is simple - just move element outside of screen and I doing that by:

```
animate(some relative layout).setDuration(300).y(-100);
```

On JellyBean everything work. But on gingerbread that animation was left white place. Where is diffrent between these two system on that simple thing?

And second weird thing on GB. When alpha animation end on some view with rounded borders all inside is gone as I expect but border is still visible...